# Java - why does char get implicitly cast to byte (and short) primitive, when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, byte, implicit-conversion

Certain functionality of the compiler puzzles me (Oracle JDK 1.7 using Eclipse).

So I've got this book that says char primitive needs to be explicitly cast to short and byte and this all makes sense due the data types' allowed ranges don't overlap.

In other words below code works (but wouldn't work without the explicit type casts):

```
char c = '&';  
byte b = (byte)c;
short s = (short)c;
```

Printing b or s correctly displays the number 38, which is the numeric equivalent of (&) in Unicode.

**Which brings me to my actual question. Why does the following work as well?**

```
byte bc = '&';
short sc = '&';
System.out.println(bc); // Correctly displays number 38 on the console
System.out.println(sc); // Correctly displays number 38 on the console
```

Now I would certainly understand the following (which works too):

```
byte bt = (byte)'&';
System.out.println(bt); // Correctly displays number 38 on the console
```

But this no-compiler-warning char to byte (and short) "sneak conversion" doesn't seem right to me.

**Can some one explain, why this is allowed?**

Could the reason be in the interpretation of the `'<char>'` itself, so that it doesn't actually ever get to a char primitive state but is handled as a numeric (octal or hexadecimal etc) value?

Comment: Simply put, the compiler can determine if a constant can safely be narrowed down. It will generate a compilte time error if there is loss of precision, try this one for comparison: byte b = '\u20AC';

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, the [specification of assignment conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) specifies that

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Your `'&'` is precisely *"a constant expression of type byte, short, char, or int"*.

Comment: Although the reference is correct (to assignment spec) the first quoted paragraph is _not_ relevant. There are no parameterized types in these assignment examples. Only the second paragraph applies.

Answer (score 7):

This is called *compile-time narrowing of constants*. It is described in section 5.2 of the Java Language Specification:

> The compile-time narrowing of constants means that code such as:
>
> ```
> byte theAnswer = 42;
> ```
>
> is allowed. Without the narrowing, the fact that the integer literal 42 has type int would
>   mean that a cast to byte would be required.

Same goes for character literals: if its value fits in a `byte`, no conversion is required; if the value does not fit, you must put in a cast, or you would get a compile error.

For example, this would not compile:

```
byte bc = '\uff12'; // Does not compile without a cast
```

but this compiles fine:

```
byte bc = (byte)'\uff12';
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the following work as well?

Because `'&'` is a constant expression whose value fits in `byte`.

JLS 14.4.2

> If a declarator has an initialization expression, the expression is evaluated and its value is assigned to the variable.

JLS 5.2

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is assigned (§15.26) to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> ....
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this explaination is enough or not, but this behavior is defined in the JLS. From the [JLS, section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a
>   constant expression (§15.28) of type
>   byte, short, char or int :
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may
>     be used if the type of the variable is
>     byte, short, or char, and the value of
>     the constant expression is
>     representable in the type of the
>     variable.
> - A narrowing primitive
>     conversion followed by a boxing
>     conversion may be used if the type of
>     the variable is :
>
>   - Byte and the value
>       of the constant expression is
>       representable in the type byte.
>   - Short
>       and the value of the constant
>       expression is representable in the
>       type short.
>   - Character and the value of
>       the constant expression is
>       representable in the type char.

Answer (score 0):

The expression '&' that is in your initializer for variable bc is a constant expression. The expression c that is in your initializer for variables b and s is not a constant expression. Java performs implicit narrowing conversions of primitives when the context requires it **when the value is the result of a constant expression** only.