# What does it mean if a byte has single quotes ( ' ' ) around a number?

Tags: java, byte

One of the questions I had for my computer science class had this question.

```
byte fun = '0';
System.out.println(fun);
```

The answer is 48, but no one in my class knows how to work it, or what it means. We know what bytes are, but what does it mean to have single quotes around them?

Comment: Google for UnicodeTable and check what index `0` character has in it (in decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in single quotes is not a `byte`, it is a `char` literal. Java translates it into its UNICODE-16 numeric value for assignment.

The reason one gets an illusion that quote-enclosed character is a byte is that Java checks the value to be in a range for a byte, and lets you skip the cast when it is not required. The same is true for integer literals assigned to variables of type `short` or `byte`:

```
byte b = 100;
```

The above will compile, even though `100` is a literal of type `int`, which is wider than `byte`, because the compiler knows that the actual value fits in a `byte`.

This is not universally true about assignments like that: if you use a character that has UNICODE-16 value greater than 128, you would get a compile-time error.

For example, this would not compile

```
byte a = 'ё';
```

triggering an error

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from char to byte

Comment: There's a typo: *wold* (would?).

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes around any character represent a character literal.

'0' is the literal of the character 0 (whose type is `char`), whose numeric value is 48. It can be assigned to a `byte` variable without an explicit type cast since 48 is a valid value for a `byte`.

Answer (score 1):

Single ticks are used to write char value literals in Java source code.

Thus '0' represents a char value; and there is an implicit cast to byte

(see [Java - why does char get implicitly cast to byte (and short) primitive, when it shouldn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063436/java-why-does-char-get-implicitly-cast-to-byte-and-short-primitive-when-it) for why that is)