# java weird assignment rules

Tags: java, char, integer, variable-assignment

```
short s = 'a';       // valid
Short ss = 'a';      // valid
int i = 'a';         // valid
Integer ii = 'a';    // invalid
```

Why Integer ii = 'a' invalid, but int i = 'a' valid?  Why Short ss ='a' valid, but Integer ii = 'a' invalid?

---

another set question:

```
byte b;
final short s = 1;
final Short ss = 1;
final int i =1;
final Integer ii = i;
final long L = 1;
final Long LL =1L;

b = s;     // valid
b = ss;    // invalid
b = i;     // valid
b = ii;    // invalid
b = L;     // invalid
b = LL;    // invalid
```

Why b = L; invalid, while b = s; valid ?

**Please, don't say it is all because JLS said so. I want to know why JLS has these inconsistent and non-intuitive rules. What did I miss?**

Comment: Because autoboxing (and primitive widening conversion) doesn't work to make a `char` an `Integer`. Try `Integer ii = (int) 'a'; `

Comment: ii is the instance of class whereas i is instance of integer datatype.

Comment: Good time to learn about 'Autoboxing and Unboxing' in java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - why does char get implicitly cast to byte (and short) primitive, when it shouldn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063436/java-why-does-char-get-implicitly-cast-to-byte-and-short-primitive-when-it)

Comment: ss is the instance of class, but Short ss = 'a' is valid. Integer ii = (int) 'a'; invalid. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the line:

```
Short s = 'a'; // is valid ...
```

Because *char* is unsigned 16-bit value (maximum value is 65,536) and *short* is signed 16-bit value (maximum value is 32,767), so there is a narrowing primitive conversion (char to short) followed by a boxing conversion (short to Short).

```
short s = 'a'; // is valid - this is a narrowing primitive conversion (char -> short)
```

These are [special cases](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression of
>   type *byte*, *short*, *char*, or *int*:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>     variable is *byte*, *short*, or *char*, and the value of the constant
>     expression is representable in the type of the variable.
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may
>   be used if the type of the variable is:
>
> - *Byte* and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
>     type *byte*.
> - *Short* and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
>     type *short*.
> - *Character* and the value of the constant expression is representable in
>     the type *char*.

Let's go to the next examples:

```
Integer ii = 'a'; // is invalid - not a special case according to Oracle docs
int i = 'a';      // is valid - widening primitive conversion (char -> int) is allowed
```

And one more case from your question:

```
byte b;
final long L = 1;
b = L // error - incompatible types
```

Why the line **b = L** is invalid? Because it isn't a special case described above and we can lose information during a cast, that's why you must perform it explicitly:

```
b = (byte) L; // is valid - narrowing primitive conversion (long -> byte)
```

Also, have a look into a very helpful [table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5-320).

There are a lot of information about all these rules in the JLS documentation and you don't need to worry about all of them. What can I say about your last question is that without an implicit narrowing conversion any integer literal would require a cast in the next cases:

```
// Cast is permitted, but not required - profit!
byte  b = (byte)  100;
short s = (short) 100;
```

Thanks to that we can change it to:

```
byte  b = 100;
short s = 100;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answering. I understand your explanations. It is all because JLS said so. But why does JLS have this weird rules? The rules are not consistent. For example;   A narrowing primitive only happens if the expression is a constant expression of type byte, short, char, or int. But not for long? what is wrong with long?

Comment: @VincentQuan a narrowing primitive conversion never makes sense for `long`, because it is the largest primitive integer type.